# Camera intent to save new image or video

Tags: android

I'm making a gallery app, and there is a Cam button, but now it only allows the user to take a picture, the video record options is disabled... how can I allow the user to save a picture OR a video?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new button to record videos with following intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.VIDEO_CAMERA");
```

Comment: I've tested but after I record the video the intent is not returning for Result in my activity! how can I do that @oli ?